# React-Native how to check SIM-CARD installed OR not in Device?

Tags: react-native, device, sim-card

In React-Native 
I want trie to check SimCard installed or not in Device

Answer (score -1):

Use appropriate plugin for that: https://github.com/pocesar/react-native-sim-data

Comment: but i want only check simcard install on Device or Not, "React-native-sim-data" give all data about sim card....